# Android, LibGDX не работает Stage()

Tags: android, libgdx

Когда вывожу через `SpriteBatch()` :

```
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(greenRegion, 10, 10);
    batch.draw(blueRegion, 100, 110);
    batch.end();
```

на все нормально, экране появляется следующая картина:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а когда пишу следующее выводится черный экран:

```
    public class MyGdxGame  implements ApplicationListener {
            private SpriteBatch batch;
            private Texture img;
            private TextureRegion greenRegion;
            private TextureRegion blueRegion;
            private Stage stage;
            private Viewport viewport;
            private Group group;
        
        
            class GreenGuad extends Actor {
                public void draw(SpriteBatch batch,float parentAlpha){
                    batch.draw(greenRegion,getX(),getY(),getWidth(),getHeight());
                }
            }
        
            class BlueGuad extends Actor {
                public void draw(SpriteBatch batch,float parentAlpha){
                    batch.draw(blueRegion,getX(),getY(),getWidth(),getHeight());
                }
            }
        
            @Override
            public void create () {
                img = new Texture("guads.png");
                batch = new SpriteBatch();
                greenRegion = new TextureRegion(img,0,0,32,32);
                blueRegion = new TextureRegion(img,32,0,32,32);
        
                viewport = new ExtendViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
                stage = new Stage(viewport,batch);
        
                BlueGuad blueGuad = new BlueGuad();
                blueGuad.setSize(100, 100);
                blueGuad.setPosition(0, 0);
        
                GreenGuad greenGuad = new GreenGuad();
                greenGuad.setSize(100,100);
                greenGuad.setPosition(110, 0);
        
                group = new Group();
                group.setSize(210, 100);
                group.addActor(blueGuad);
                group.addActor(greenGuad);
        
                stage.addActor(group);
                group.setPosition(0, 50);
            }
        
            @Override
            public void render () {
                stage.draw();
                stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
            }
        }
```

мне нужно с помощью `Stage()` вывести на экран.
Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте не использовать `Group`, а сразу добавить актеров на сцену:

```
 stage.addActor(blueGuad); 
 stage.addActor(greenGuad);
```

Только что глянул в свой рабочий проект, у меня так организовано.

Comment: пробовал, так же ничего не выходит

Comment: Попробуйте добавить в GreenGuad и BlueGuad в метод draw эту строчку: super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);

Comment: добавил super.draw(batch, parentAlpha); не помогло

Comment: вот тут public void draw(SpriteBatch batch,float parentAlpha) поменял SpriteBatch на Batch и все заработало. а в чем разница между ними?